# Ajax return JSON object with extra readyState, responseText, status and statusText

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, ajax

I made an ajax call to parse a JSON object. The object is called perfectly by ajax. But the problem is when I return the object it add 4 more property readyState, responseText, status and statusText to my JSON object.

IJSON object that i want is

```
{"sysload":{"label":"System Load","data":[[0,2546],[1,10307],[2,16064],[3,26617],[4,21310],[5,1439],[6,1772],[7,2741],[8,25930],[9,23739]]}}
```

What I got

```
{"readyState":4,"responseText":"{\"sysload\":{\"label\":\"System Load\",\"data\":[[0,15218],[1,15299],[2,3136],[3,26489],[4,7358],[5,20767],[6,11372],[7,565],[8,18122],[9,24635]]}}\t","status":200,"statusText":"OK"}
```

How to remove those weird 4 property and backslash. Here is my php code--

```
<?php
    function get_server_load() 
    {
        $load=rand();
        return $load;
    }
    $data = array();
    $data['sysload'] = array();
    $data['sysload']['label'] = "System Load";
    for ($i=0; $i < 10; $i++) { 
        $data['sysload']['data'][] = array($i, get_server_load());
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

And Here is my javascript Code:

```
function getRealtime() {
    return $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'cpuload.php',
        data: {
            'get_server_load': 1
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
            dataxxx = data;
        }
    });
    return dataxxx;
}
```

The return data is containing those extra property, but in ajax success callback it is absolutely good. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: You would not use `return` before $.ajax. Also, as a good practice, initialize dataxxx (`var dataxxx = ''`) before calling $.ajax

Comment: I initialized that

Comment: where and how do you get that output? or what do you get when you `console.log(data)` in `success` callback?

Comment: is there a particular reason for switching off 'async'?

Comment: Is the url correct? I just tested your code, removing `return` from before $.ajax and it worked.

Comment: Everything is correct. I got the actual data on success callback function but when i try to return the data it mix some extra value to dataxxx global variable

Comment: Hicaro -- please test the output twice. Once inside success function and other outside function using dataxxx variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I executed this:

```
function getRealtime() {
    var dataxxx;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'cpuload.php',
        data: {
            'get_server_load': 1
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
            dataxxx = data;
        }
    });
    return dataxxx;
}
console.log(getRealtime());
```

It returns `{"sysload":{"label":"System Load","data":[[0,16333],[1,29610],[2,32616],[3,15902],[4,5212],[5,29171],[6,12775],[7,15058],[8,3307],[9,14984]]}}`